# Tombstone records not processed in Kstream-Ktable join

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-join

I have this kstream topology:

```
KStream<String, Data> eventStream = streamsBuilder.stream("event",
        Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), eventSerde);

KTable<String, Result> resultKTable = streamsBuilder.table("result",
        Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), resultSerde));

eventStream.leftJoin(resultKTable, new Joiner())
        .to("result", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), resultSerde));
```

When I sent tombstone record in "event" topic, it gives me this error

```
Skipping record due to null join key or value. key=[3428642] value=[null] topic=[event] partition=[0] offset=[21]
```

**EDIT**
I did the following workaround to handle tombstone records:

```
eventStream.filter((k,v) -> v != null)
           .leftJoin(resultKTable, new Joiner())
           .to("result", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), resultSerde));
eventStream.filter((k,v) -> v == null).to("result");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not an error, but warning.

As written in Kafka Streams [documentation for KStream-KTable left join](https://kafka.apache.org/31/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#kstream-ktable-join):

> Input records for the stream with a null key or a null value are
> ignored and do not trigger the join

So, this is expected scenario.

---

Side note:
There is written blogpost at [luppeng.wordpress.com](https://luppeng.wordpress.com/2022/10/01/kstreams-globalktable-left-join-drops-record-when-keyvaluemapper-returns-null-from-kafka-streams-library-v2-7-onwards/) about this and possible workaround, which might come handy.

Comment: Got it. I did another workaround to handle tombstones. Is that a right approach? Updated the question

Comment: Looks good to me (you might also use split or merge streams before sending to sink "result" topic" - but in this case there are no real benefits)